Clojure test, how to test if a namespace is being used by another namespace
We have namespaces that are only used for older years, and have been improved for future years.
And we want to test that these old namespaces are not required or accessible from future years
We have tried find-ns it seems to show mappings, but doesn't seem to show the namespaces we are looking for, whether it is required or not.
also tried 'ns-map' but this is just access the same mappings as above.
any advice appreciated, thanks.

Please provide
a MRE

Checkout ns-refers It might help. Or give an example
